# Inserting php variables into sql statements

Tags: php, mysql

Changing the question as I have better information.

The following query

```
function gamesWaiting($join, $type, $status, $u)
{
    global $database;
    $q = "SELECT g.home_user, g.away_user, g.home_score, g.home_team, g.away_score, g.away_team, g.id, f.name, f.game, 
         uh.username AS home_username, ua.username AS away_username
          FROM ".TBL_FOOT_GAMES." g
          INNER JOIN ".TBL_USERS." uh ON uh.id = g.home_user
          INNER JOIN ".TBL_USERS." ua ON ua.id = g.away_user
          INNER JOIN ".$join." f ON f.id = g.leagueid
          WHERE g.type = '$type' && g.{$u}_user = '$_SESSION[id]' && g.status = '$status'";
    return mysql_query($q, $database->myConnection());
}
```

The only part that isn't working is the

```
".$join."
```

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Thankyou

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resourc

Comment: Hey. In your function before `return mysql_query($q, $database->myConnection());` put this line `echo $q;` and then run your script again. You'll get the query printed to the screen. Take that query and try to run in directly to mysql and see what error it returns. Put that error here. Or you can show us the query from your function

Comment: Complete your code, the error is regarding the mysql_num_rows function that is not in the code, so i suppose you have forgot a part.

Comment: The problem appears to be the $u variable I am trying to put into the query. Just putting it in with nothing around makes the variable read $u_user, '$u'_user doesnt work either. What would?

Comment: I put curly brackets and it worked!

Comment: The $join variable is the only thing stopping this working now. any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean it's "not working"? Is the value of $join not inserted into the string? Do what Octopus-Paul said, echo $q.

Comment: Well if I put the variable information straight into the query, it works. When I take it out, the query doesnt produce anything and gives a mysql_query error. So it must be the syntax I am using for the $join variable.

Comment: If you echo $q and paste it here, it will be easier to suggest an answer. This has nothing to do with MySQL querying or how to concatenate strings (you are doing both correctly). If something is "not working" with the $join variable, then the reason is that $join does not contain what you think it contains.

Comment: I did that and have now fixed it. Will use this tecnique again in teh future. Very useful :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query search for a table name TBL_FOOT_FRIENDLY, not what your constant's referring table name. (From your code TBL_FOOT_FRIENDLY may defined as foot_friendly in database)

Comment: The  ". ." makes this query work. The other joins are fine, just wondering if the way I am putting a variable into the query is messing it up!

Comment: So is TBL_FOOT_FRIENDLY really the table name?

Comment: It's the name I have given it in the constants page.

Answer (score 0):

assign the constant value in a variable and pass this variable in to function

```
$tbl=TBL_FOOT_FRIENDLY;
$results = $footdb->gamesWaiting($tbl, "1", "2", "away");
```

or remove the double quote from around the constant and pass

```
$results = $footdb->gamesWaiting(TBL_FOOT_FRIENDLY, "1", "2", "away");
```

and try.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem appears to be the $u variable I am trying to put into the query. Just putting it in with nothing around makes the variable read $u_user, '$u'_user doesnt work either. What would?

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
INNER JOIN '" . $join . "' f ON f.id = g.leagueid
```

Notice the single-quotes enclosing the double-quotes around `. $join .`

Comment: This doesnt make any difference.